# Leanback VerticalGridView height: wrap_content

Tags: android, leanback, android-wrap-content

I have a VerticalGridView in which i plan to use multiple VerticalGridViews.
Wrap_Content does nothing for a VerticalGridView if its set on it's height, The GridLayoutManager simply ignores it if the view is in a normal view, and it does match_parent it seems. If it is in another Vertical Scrolling view the height is 0.
I cannot override the GridLayoutManager without duplicating the entire leanback library.

How can I achieve wrap_content for it?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @AnoopM it seems I found solution! Look below for my answer

Comment: - Change it's layout manager from `leanback.widget.GridLayoutManager` to `recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager`: 
 - in xml, set android:layout_height="wrap_content"



`verticalGridView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, VerticalGridView.VERTICAL, false)`

Answer (score -2):

setColumnWidth method can be used to achieve it:

```
gridView.setColumnWidth (ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
```

In my case I extend VerticalGridView and call this method in constructor to make WRAP_CONTENT default behavior

Comment: How can it work ? It applies to the width, not the height. In my case, unfortunately your solution did not work :(